# Accessing JavaScript module method using string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a module created in JavaScript.

```
var test = function () {
    var validate = function () {
        alert("fg");
    };
    return {
        validate: validate
    };
}();
```

Now, can I access the above module using  a string? For example:

```
$(function () {
    var s = "test"; 
    s.validate();   // error  
});
```

Well, I tried, but no luck so far, because "s" is string. Is there any way to convert this string into above module object and access the `validate` method?

Comment: You can, if you declare your `test` function as global. Is it a global function or namespaced?

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of doing this? I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `eval()`.

```
var test = function () {
    var validate = function () {
        alert("fg");
    };
    return {
        validate: validate
    };
}();
$(function () {
    var s = eval("test"); //Here
    s.validate();  
});
```

**For a side note:**

Use `eval()` carefully. From the ***[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)***:

> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your webpage / extension.

Comment: I think it pertinent to add that you should avoid `eval` at almost all costs. It is slow and dangerous, and usually indicates a poor design in your code. Instead of incorporating `eval`, OP should rethink program design.

Answer (score 2):

s is a String, so if you want to call validate on s you would have to extend the String prototype

```
String.prototype.validate = function () {
    return alert("fg")
};
```

Or

But if you want to create an Object called "Test"

```
var test = function () {
    var validate = function () {
        alert("fg");
    };
    return {
        validate: validate
    };
}();

$(function () {
    var s = test(); // Here 
    s.validate();   
});
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. Note how the value of the string is the same as the name of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to declare the function as global.

```js
window.test = function () {
  var validate = function () {
    alert("fg");
  };
  return {
    validate: validate
  };
}();


$(function () {
  var s = "test"; 
  window[s].validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```